# Remove People From Drop Down If Exist in Other Fields

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have a PowerApp created using SharePoint list with multiple Person or Group type. The PowerApp has a form that allows user to select employees from M365 for a given field.

The problem is that I would like to remove person if they are already assigned/select.

This is a screenshot of the powerapp. Currently if a person is selected in Window1 they are still available to select in Window2. I would like to have that person not show as a selection option in Window2.

[image]

One additional catch is that the SharePoint list has Allow multiple selections enabled. Greatly appreciate any guidance/advice to solve this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window 1:
Onchange - Set(window1SelectedItem, Self.Selected.Value);

Items - Filter(items, Value <> window2SelectedItem, Value <> window3SelectedItem, Value <> window4SelectedItem, Value <> window5SelectedItem);

Window 2:
Onchange - Set(window2SelectedItem, Self.Selected.Value);

Items - Filter(items, Value <> window1SelectedItem, Value <> window3SelectedItem, Value <> window4SelectedItem, Value <> window5SelectedItem);

Window 3:
Onchange - Set(window3SelectedItem, Self.Selected.Value);

Items - Filter(items, Value <> window1SelectedItem, Value <> window2SelectedItem, Value <> window4SelectedItem, Value <> window5SelectedItem);

Window 4:
Onchange - Set(window4SelectedItem, Self.Selected.Value);

Items - Filter(items, Value <> window1SelectedItem, Value <> window2SelectedItem, Value <> window3SelectedItem, Value <> window5SelectedItem);

Window 5:
Onchange - Set(window5SelectedItem, Self.Selected.Value);
Items - Filter(items, Value <> window1SelectedItem, Value <> window2SelectedItem, Value <> window3SelectedItem, Value <> window4SelectedItem);

if this answer is helpful feel free to accept it as a correct answer.

Comment: oh wow! Thanks for taking the time to post this detailed response. I will test and report back. thanks again.

Comment: There is an error when setting the variable. The data type in SharePoint list is Person or Group with Allow multiple selections. 

https://imgur.com/02DZt70

Comment: I was able to get this working. Thanks for the guidance. I had to tweak it a bit.  

  `code` Items - Filter(colEmployees3,Name,!(Name in varWindow2.Name),!(Name in varWindow3.Name),!(Name in varWindow4.Name),!(Name in varWindow5.Name))`code`  

Like you indicated I put everything in a variable but these were combo box and the code was a bit different.  

`code` OnChange - Set(varWindow1, Self.SelectedItems.Name);`code`